# How can I Install the Old TweetDeck version on Ubuntu 12.10 64bits?

Tags: 64-bit, adobe-air

I've tried to install Adobe Air 2.6 and then the old version of TweetDeck (0.38.2) but it's not working to me. Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Air for Linux is no longer supported by Adobe. Their 64 bit support was pretty bad to begin with. The chances of you getting this to work well are pretty slim. I would recommend just using wine.

You can use the older version of tweetdeck by installing air in wine then installing tweetdeck. This should work quite well (though it's obviously not ideal).

You also install the newer version of tweetdeck via wine.

Here are some links to get you started.

[New Version Post](http://apipeandakeyboard.com/2012/05/27/running-tweetdeck-on-linux-mint-13-mate/), [A new version announcement](http://techhamlet.com/2011/12/twitter-updates-tweetdeck-and-now-its-finally-free-of-air/) stating wine works, [Some poor instructions](http://bperucchi.blogspot.com/2009/07/install-adobe-air-15-as-wine-in-ubuntu.html) for air and wine, and finally [the winehq page](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=25794) for air.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it working not too hard: make sure to read through all the steps first

http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12102341&postcount=2